# borrar espacios en blanco en tabla mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

tengo una tabla en mysql, y un campo llamado referencia

en el campo referencia están estos datos separados por espacios en blanco, en algunos casos 1 espacio en blanco 2 , 3, 4 o combinados así como este ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito que despues de un query

> tep_db_query("update " . TABLE . " set referencia = ???????");

el resultado final sea una tabla con los campos ordenados sin espacios en blanco:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si quieres quitar todos los espacios en blanco puedes usar la función `Replace`.

```
update TABLE set referencia = replace(referencia, ' ', '');
```

Debes tener cuidado, ya que la puedes liar parda haciendo estas cosas.

Haz primero una `select` para saber si es lo que esperas..

Puedes ver el uso de replace [aquí](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-replace-function.php)

Comment: Cabe decir que esa consulta sería válida solamente en un campo de **una sola palabra**. En campos con datos como `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet` la consulta sería desastrosa, produciendo esto: `Loremipsumdolorsitamet`. Por otra parte, viendo que son sólo números, preguntaría a @IvanDiazPerez por qué esa columna no se declaró con un tipo de dato numérico. A veces hay que ir más lejos en la solución de ciertos problemas. Saludos.